# Sum of values in column V1 based on conditions set in V2 in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, sum

I want to create the sum of a number of values in a column, based on following conditions:

Say I have following data

```
Z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
```

giving me

```
V1   V2
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
10   1
```

Now I only want to sum of values in V1 between the first 1 in V2 and the first value in V2 that is followed by four zeroes. In this example this would be the sum of [3,1] and [4,1] since [3,2] contains the first zero and [4,2] is the first value that is followed by four zeroes in resp. [5,2], [6,2], [7,2] and [8,2].

I tried following loop and variations on it but it keeps giving errors.

```
for(j in 1:10){
  ifelse(V2(j) == 1,
         (for i in (j:(10-j+1)){
           ifelse (V2(i+1) == 0 & V2(i+2) == 0 & V2(i+3) == 0 & V2(i+4) == 0, total <- sum(V1(c(j:i))), next)})
         , next)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple for loop:

```
Z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
index1 <- which(Z[,2]==1)
sum <- 0
if (length(index1) >  0) {
  index1 <- index1[1]
  index2 <- NULL
  indices <- index1-1+which(Z[index1:nrow(Z),2]==0)
  for (i in 1:(length(indices)-3)) {
    if (all((indices[i]+(0:3))==indices[i:(i+3)])) {
      index2 <- (indices[i] - 1) # position of first consecutive 0s after the first 1  is indices[i]
      break
    }
  }
  sum <- ifelse(!is.null(index2), sum(Z[index1:index2, 1]), 0)  
}
sum
[1] 7
```

Comment: This works great. Is there a way to include an option for when there is 1) no first 1 so all values in V2 are 0 and 2) is no sequence of 4 zeroes? In the first case, the sum should be 0, in the latter case the sum should be for a fixed amount for instance between the first 1 and 10 periods later. Sorry for the additional questions.

Comment: then the output should be zero.

Comment: what is the fixed amount in the 2nd case?

Comment: Can you do a fixed sum of x values for both cases? For instance 8, either from the beginning when everything in V2 is 0, or from the first 1 when there just isn't a sequence of 4 zeroes in V2.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution using base R `rle/inverse.rle` functions

```
res <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(Z[, 2] == 0), values[lengths < 4] <- 0))
sum(Z[which.max(Z[, 2]) : (which.max(res) - 1), 1])
# [1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
sum(Z[,1][rep(which.max(!rowSums(do.call(cbind, shift(Z[,2],2:5,
                              type = "lead", fill = 0)))),2) + 0:1])
#[1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `rollapply` from `zoo` package can be,

```
library(zoo)
ind <- c(which(Z[,2] == 1)[1], which(rollapply(Z[,2], 4, by = 1, sum) == 0)[1] - 1)
sum(Z[ind,1])
#[1] 7
```